# Replace " " string with null in hadoop and spark

Tags: java, string, hive, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have a project which uses hdfs, hive, spark technologies . When i import data , for numeric fields if data is not present it will be replaced with null. But for strings it will be replaced by empty string " " . For solving this issue I used this line while i create table in hive.

```
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='');
```

But still when i convert this into spark data frame the empty strings are represented as "" instead of null

What can be the reason..?
Is some of the properties in hive does not support in spark..?

Answer (score 0):

@Manu,

Please use this as an abstract for your conversion problem into spark data frames:

```
## Create a sample DataFrame
testDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(col1='foo', col2=1), Row(col1='', col2=2), Row(col1=None, col2='')])
```

### These function will convert all the empty strings to null as you requested

```
 def blank_if_null(z):
        return when(col(z) != "", col(z)).otherwise(None)

dfWithEmptyReplaced = testDF.withColumn("col1", blank_as_null("col1"))
```